# Background task in Liftweb environment

Tags: scala, lift

I must write daemon and I want to use Models for connecting to the database and some useful Lift classes.
Is it possible to run analog of Rails's rake tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is similar question on the Scala community group. The answer is to use Actors to do background processing.

http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/ce536649e6e83867/ffde3a3d619adf9d?lnk=gst&q=background#ffde3a3d619adf9d