# Slick and liftweb

Tags: scala, slick, lift

As far as I understand latest Slick documentation, there is no straight way to get results immediately from Slick queries, as they always return Future (wrapped, but still).

And liftweb requires database results here and now to render the pages.

So, what's the correct way to perform such tasks besides `Await.result`?
Let's assume that we are talking about something like

`"table.list" #> someDbRows.map`

and not about ajax / comet which seems to be perfectly fit for Futures.

Thank you.

Comment: Worth mentioning, in Lift 3 you can bind the right side of a CSS selector transform directly to a future (Scala future or Lift future). Glad you found the answer for your issue though :)

Comment: @AntonioSalazarCardozo  may I ask you to provide an example or link to documentation? :) I somehow totally missed that one.  Thank you!

Comment: There's an example of [how you can achieve this in Lift 2.6](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/TF6qUChAdbY/oAT1jyVJIKgJ) (with some supporting code), and you can also look at [this example](https://github.com/Shadowfiend/lift-future-canbind-example/blob/lift_30/src/main/scala/code/snippet/HelloWorld.scala) for how it works in Lift 3. To save you some effort though: `import net.liftweb.http._` and then just use the future on the right hand side. No additional work needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some investigation, there seems to be no straight way to delegate CssSel answer to Future. The distinct cases are lift comet and lift REST. So, the only way to use Slick in a direct CssSel request is to `Await.result` with reasonable timings.

**Update**: still, there is a way to [use Futures in a righthand expression part](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/liftweb/TF6qUChAdbY/oAT1jyVJIKgJ) and more in  [Lift 3.0 changes](https://github.com/Shadowfiend/lift-future-canbind-example/blob/lift_30/src/main/scala/code/snippet/HelloWorld.scala), thanks to [Antonio Salazar Cardozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206493/antonio-salazar-cardozo)

There is a similar questions here: [Background task in Liftweb environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383076/background-task-in-liftweb-environment?rq=1)
and brief explanation https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/zlNmSeboOGc

P.S.: Dear SO community, please stop farming reputation providing unrelated answers from top 3 google and raging when they gets down voted. I understand that SO slowly became HR hiring platform, but this is not why SO exists.